# Webkit Gradient syntax

Tags: webkit, css, gradient

I've been reading about the `-webkit-gradient` property and I don't understand it.

Radial:

```
-webkit-gradient(radial, 105 105, 20, 112 120, 50, from(#ff5f98), to(rgba(255,1,136,0)), color-stop(75%, #ff0188)),
```

What does `105 105, 20, 112 120, 50` mean?

Linear:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 40 50, 50 50, color-stop(0.0, yellow),
            color-stop(0.5, orange), color-stop(1.0, red));
```

What does `40 50, 50 50` mean?

Answer (score 7):

[Webkit gradient documentation](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/)

> For a radial gradient, the first two arguments represent a start circle with origin (x0, y0) and radius r0, and the next two arguments represent an end circle with origin (x1, y1) and radius r1.

So for radial: "105 105, 20, 112 120, 50", it's a circle starting at 105px left and 105px top with a radius of 20px and ending at a circle 112px left and 120px top with a radius of 50px;

For linear: "40 50, 50 50", start at 40px left 50px top, and continue to 50px left 50px top.

Comment: Are webkit gradients compatible with IE?

Comment: @Solidariti: Nope. IE isn't a WebKit browser.